# „German“ quotation marks in .cls file

Tags: packages, titles, punctuation, document-classes

I have a class file which, among other things, generates a title page for my paper. The name of of my school, which appears at the top of the title page, is hard-coded into the class file.

I would like to be able to utilize `\RequirePackage[serbian]{babel}` along with `` "` "' `` within the .cls file to get German-style quotation marks („“) in my document, but when I try including the package it just doesn't work. Here's the code along with the output:

```
{\large \textsc{Gimnazija "`Branislav Petronijevi\'{c}"'}\par}
{\small Ub, Vuka Karad\v{z}i\'{c}a 15 \par}
```

[image: Bad German quotation mark parsing]

Yet, if I copy the code over to the .tex file that holds the document, it works just fine with the babel package. Is the class file for some reason not including the package? Are there any alternatives to what I'm trying to achieve?

If you would like to take a look at the class file, you can do so here: http://pastebin.com/KsXjERng
It's something I got off the web and made edits to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Package `babel` makes the shorthand active in `\begin{document}` to avoid troubling classes and packages with active characters. `\shorthandon` and `\shorthandoff` enables and disables shorthands:

```
\shorthandon{"}%
{\large \textsc{Gimnazija "`Branislav Petronijevi\'{c}"'}\par}
{\small Ub, Vuka Karad\v{z}i\'{c}a 15 \par}
\shorthandoff{"}%
```

Or avoid the use of shorthands in the class file:

```
{\large \textsc{Gimnazija \quotedblbase Branislav Petronijevi\'{c}\textquotedblleft}\par}
{\small Ub, Vuka Karad\v{z}i\'{c}a 15 \par}
```

This way the text remains independent from package `babel` and its shorthands.